# Función recursiva en Python

Tags: python, funciones, recursión, fibonacci

estoy teniendo problemas para asimilar el funcionamiento de un ejemplo de recursividad en las funciones de Python.En el ejemplo dado se busca retornar el valor correspondiente de una secuencia fibonacci en relación a una posición que se pasa como argumento a la función.Abajo dejo el código de la función.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
         return n
    else:
         return fibonacci(n -1) + fibonacci(n -2)
```

Bien,para entender como funcionaba esto hice lo siguiente:

```
Cuando n = 5 --> 4 + 3 = 7
Cuando n = 4 --> 3 + 2 = 5
Cuando n = 3 --> 2 + 1 = 3
Cuando n = 2 --> 1 + 0 = 1 
Y por ultimo,como la condición dice que si n == a 0 o 1 retorne n..
Cuando n = 1 --> 1
```

Talvez mi manera de analizarlo esta mal y eso es a lo que voy.. entiendo que la sucesión se da sumando dos dígitos anteriores y así sucesivamente hasta el infinito,lo que no logro comprender es como se realizan los cálculos y se van asignando los valores detrás de las líneas de código en este ejercicio en específico.
Si alguien me pudiera explicar se lo agradecería un montón.

Comment: Calcula `fibonacci(5)` usando lápiz y papel. Cada vez que veas una llamada, toma otro hoja en blanco para escribir. Cada vez que veas un `return`, descarta la hoja y pasa el resultado a la que ahora es la "ultima hoja".

Comment: Hola,comprendo lo que dices..se que si pongo 5 como argumento -posicion se corresponderá con 5 en fibonacci y si pongo 7 se corresponderá con 13 y asi.. A lo que voy es,necesito saber cómo se realizan esos cálculos y se van asignando los valores en el ejercicio dado..y así comprenderlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo publico por aquí para que se pueda ver la imagen.

Imagínate que quieres saber el numero Fibonacci en la posición 6, que se correspondería al número 8. Llamamos a ese método donde n va a ser 6, y como no es ni un 1 ni un 0, llamamos otra vez al método con n-1 (5), y n-2 (4), y la suma de esos resultados va a ser lo que devuelva `fibonacci(6)`, por lo tanto llamamos a `fibonacci(5)` (que sería `fibonacci(n-1)`) y a `fibonacci(4)` (que sería `fibonacci(n-2)`), y se vuelve a repetir la misma operación. Va a llegar un punto en el que llamemos a `fibonacci(0)` y `fibonacci(1)`, el cual va a retornar ese mismo número, por lo tanto ya tenemos un valor del anterior método y lo podemos sumar.

Viendolo con la imagen, llamamos a `fibonacci(6)`, que devolverá el resultado de sumar `fibonacci(5)` y `fibonacci(4)`, que este último devolverá la suma de `fibonacci(3)` y `fibonacci(2)`, que este último devolverá la suma de `fibonacci(1)` (que es 1), y `fibonacci(0)` que es 0, entonces `fibonacci(2)` devolverá 2, que se sumará al valor de `fibonacci(3)` (que su valor es 2), y así continuamos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Piensa en esto como un método que se va a llamar así mismo con otro parámetro.
Y en la imagen fijate como en cuento llega a 0 o a 1 deja de bajar, en ese momento empieza a sumar hacia arriba esos 0 y 1, que son los que se devuelven con el método.

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero quedaría mejor dividiendola en párrafos, para darle más "aire" al texto. Así todo junto cuesta un poco seguirlo.

Comment: Muy bueno!! Ahora lo entiendo,bastante diferente a como me lo planteaba en la cabeza.viendolo ahora es tan sencillo entederlo..Que me siento un pavo jaja mil gracias @cls